# Can the transaction order be determined by the gas charges on the BSC chain

Tags: blockchain

I send a request of 6GWEI and 5GWEI on the same block, will 6GWEI be the first to clinch a deal?
If not what circumstance can be affected what special case can see ah ~

Comment: Is this a programming question? Do you have code to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special case is that 99.9 percent of the block is GAS high

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).